# Default image is not getting replaced by the captured image for the first time

Tags: android

In my app, I am capturing the image and setting it in second activity and then after doing some operations, uploading it to server.If the image exists for the particular id,then displaying that image in the image view in the first activity else displaying some default image. When I try to upload the image by capturing image,if there is already image exists for that id in the server,captured image is updating in the image-view of first activity.If there is no image for that id,and when I setting the captured image it is not getting displayed.If I login same id,for the second time it is displaying. How to refresh the first activity after returning from second activity. Here is my code:

```
StudentDetails.java:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_details);

   String IMAGE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;

    resultIv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV);
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV))
            .execute(IMAGE_URL);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Bitmap imageData = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");        
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Image.class);
            i.putExtra("name", imageData);         
            startActivityForResult(i,3);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    } 
  else if (requestCode == 3) {
        onResume();
    }
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {  
    // After a pause OR at startup
    super.onResume();
    getIntent();
    //Refresh your stuff here
    String img_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_name");
    String img_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_path");
    String IMAGE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV))
            .execute(IMAGE_URL);
}


StudentDetails.xml:
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/man2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

Image.java:
```

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
    resultIv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    resultIv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    String auid_t = getIntent().getStringExtra("auid_num");
    String imei_t = getIntent().getStringExtra("imei_num");
    auid_s.setText(auid_t);
    imei_s.setText(imei_t);

    text_position.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    doneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    doneBtn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    text_upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonUpload1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cropView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    resultIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    PassImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cropView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resultIv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_position.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            doneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text_size.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PassImageBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            StampImageBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Bitmap photo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
            resultIv.setImageBitmap(photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            int x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 413, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 531, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            cropView.of(Uri.fromFile(finalFile)).withAspect(x, y).initialize(Image.this);
        }
    });

    StampImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cropView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resultIv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_position.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            doneBtn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text_size.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PassImageBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            StampImageBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Bitmap photo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
            resultIv.setImageBitmap(photo);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            int x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 56, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 7, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            cropView.of(Uri.fromFile(finalFile)).withAspect(x, y).initialize(Image.this);
        }
    });

    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Image.this, null, "Please wait…", true, false);
            cropView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_position.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resultIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonUpload1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    croppedBitmap = cropView.getOutput();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // cropped image set
                            resultIv.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
                        }
                    });
                    Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
                    CropUtil.saveOutput(Image.this, destination, croppedBitmap, 1);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    doneBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Image.this, null, "Please wait…", true, false);
            cropView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doneBtn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_position.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resultIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonUpload1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    croppedBitmap = cropView.getOutput();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // cropped image set
                            resultIv.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
                        }
                    });
                    Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
                    CropUtil.saveOutput(Image.this, destination, croppedBitmap, 1);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });
    buttonUpload1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadImage1();
        }
    });

    pinButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            text_position.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doneBtn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonUpload1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cropView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultIv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_size.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            PassImageBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            StampImageBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    pinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}//end

private void uploadImage() {
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Image.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    resultIv.buildDrawingCache();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Image.this, StudentDetails.class);
                    setResult(2, intent);
                    finish();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(Image.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage(croppedBitmap);
            String auid_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("auid_num");
            String imei_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("imei_num");

            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            //Adding parameters
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_AUID, auid_no);
            params.put(KEY_IMEI, imei_no);

            return params;
        }
    };
    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void uploadImage1() {
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Image.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    resultIv.buildDrawingCache();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Image.this, StudentDetails.class);

                    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", croppedBitmap);
                    setResult(2, intent);
                    finish();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(Image.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage1(croppedBitmap);
            String auid_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("auid_num");
            String imei_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("imei_num");

            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            //Adding parameters
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_AUID, auid_no);
            params.put(KEY_IMEI, imei_no);

            return params;
        }
    };
    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int width = 413;
    int height = 531;
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

public String getStringImage1(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int width = (int) 56.69;
    int height = (int) 70.87;
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(2, intent);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

set image in `onActivityResult()` dont called onResume again.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Bitmap imageData = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            // set image here 
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(imageData);

            //Intent i = new Intent(this, Image.class);
            //i.putExtra("name", imageData);         
            //startActivityForResult(i,3);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    } 
  else if (requestCode == 3) {
        onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this .It is displaying the captured image.But I want to display the result of cropped image which am uploading to the server.

Comment: your add incomplete code of `Image` activity where you are croping cant help with code. ....and where are you croping?

Comment: croping is in an other class and you want to crop and show your result in back activity imageview right?

Comment: I have added complete code in my qtn..Yes..I want to crop and show the result in first activity.

Answer (score 0):

We've done the same scenario in our project, we have used third party library for cropping the image.After cropping the image,we pass intent to previous activity to handle the crop.Here is the code,

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri croppedUri = Crop.getOutput(result);
        File outPutFile = new File(croppedUri.getPath());
        mImagePath = outPutFile.getAbsolutePath();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = mImagePath;
        Point size = Utility.getDisplayPoint(mActivity);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = (width * 9) / 16;
        Logger.i("height", height + "");
        Logger.i("cropped path", outPutFile.getAbsolutePath() + "");
        changeBeamPosterDimension(height, width);
        setPic(mImagePath);
    }
```